# python: import global variable from parent directory

Tags: python, global-variables, python-import

```
applications/
    app.py
    extensions.py
    controllers/
        __init__.py
        inner.py
```

app.py

```
import inner
from extensions import aaa
inner.test()
```

extensions.py

```
import os
aaa = os.system
```

__init__.py

```
from inner import *
```

inner.py

```
from extensions import aaa
def test():
    aaa('pwd')
```

My project structure and code is described above, and the program will start from app.py.
Why does this work? How is aaa imported in inner.py? 

Why can we directly import from extensions.py which located in parent directory?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't importing from the "parent directory", you're importing from `applications/`. That `applications/` happens to be the parent directory is a coincidence.

Comment: I am sorry but I still don't quite understand. Why can I directly import from `applications/`

Comment: Because it's in `sys.path`, same as any directory that can be imported from.

Comment: Do the import statement in the inner.py use the same sys.path as the import statement in app.py?

Comment: All import statements everywhere in the Python program use the same `sys,path` unless it is explicitly modified.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which .py you are importing to, and which directory subfolder you are importing from. When importing in python, that .py file got to be in the same folder or subfolder directory. Try to change the directory of extensions.py file to the .py file you want to import global variable from. My answer is almost the same as the person answered before me. also your questions aren't clear.